# Finding a book series, I read the first book awhile ago and would like to finish the series

Tags: science-fiction, book, series

I read a book a while ago and I'm try to remember its name.

The book was about a an outcast who used to be a the general of a rebellion against a colony of planets. These planets had faster than light capabilities using radioactive tracers as pathways.

The main character, the ex general, find an abundance of this radioactive material on this hostile, desolate planet he was banned to. He also finds this silver water that implants the conciousness of the previous inhabitants into humans.

If anyone know the name of this book series, I would be thankful.

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE! I'm afraid questions about existing works of literature are off-topic here - this site is for assisting people with their *own* writing - but this would be on-topic on [SciFi.SE](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/) if you want to try asking there.

Comment: Thank you, I'll post the same question over there then.